# Can't move a subgroup to top group (Keycloak Admin REST API)

Tags: keycloak

I was able to move a group under other groups using `POST /{realm}/groups/{id}/children` endpoint. However, I can't move the group back to top level.

I can't find any endpoint to do that in the API reference: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_groups_resource

One weird workaround that came to my mind was deleting and re-creating the group. But then, user relationships will be lost, I'm afraid.

How can I move a group to top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `POST /{realm}/groups` method with group id in request body to move a group to the root. If you get 500 error pass `name` attribute as well. Keycloak uses provided group name to verify that no other group with the same name exists in top level.

```
POST https://keycloak/admin/realms/master/groups

{
    "id": "6018073e-1556-4795-9ab9-c22be2615f16",
    "name": "Group Name"
}
```

Comment: "id" was sufficient (Admin REST API, v6)

Comment: In Admin REST API, v7 you need both, name and id